# Kile structure view

Tags: sectioning, kile

I'm discovering Kile. The structure view is useful, but it would be very nice to have numbered sections in this view, in order to be able to jump quickly to section 54 for instance.
Do you know if it is possible, or if another tex editor provides this feature?